# Can we Make a Multi-witness transactions using cardano Serialization Lib?

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, multisig

**My Goal is to Transfer NFTs from one Wallet to another and use second wallet to cover my transaction fee.**
According to this article https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/multi-witness-transactions-cli/ this is possible can any one Point out where is my mistake.

**Here is my code for Creating the TX**

```
  try {
 // Policy For FiNFTS
    const policyId = Buffer.from(
      Wallet.nativeScript.hash(0).to_bytes()
    ).toString("hex");
    // Asset Utxo We Want to Transfer
    const SenderUtxos = await getLockedUtxosByAsset(
      Sender.paymentAddr,
      policyId + Asset
    );
    console.log(SenderUtxos);
    //Creating TX
    let { txBuilder, utxos } = await getTxBuilderAndUtxos(Wallet);
    //Adding Asset Output To the Receiver
    const MultiAsset = lib.MultiAsset.new();
    const Assets = lib.Assets.new();

    const assetName = lib.AssetName.new(Buffer.from(Asset, "hex"));
    const assetNumber = lib.BigNum.from_str("1");
    Assets.insert(assetName, assetNumber);

    MultiAsset.insert(Wallet.nativeScript.hash(0), Assets);

    txBuilder.add_output(
      lib.TransactionOutputBuilder.new()
        .with_address(lib.Address.from_bech32(Receiver.paymentAddr))
        .next()
        .with_asset_and_min_required_coin(
          MultiAsset,
          lib.BigNum.from_str("38890")
        )
        .build()
    );

    // Add Asset Utxo To Our Input Utxo List
    let converted = await Promise.all(
      SenderUtxos.map(async (utxo) => {
        console.log(utxo);
        return await utxoFromJson(
          utxo,
          lib.Address.from_bech32(Sender.paymentAddr).to_bytes()
        );
      })
    );
    converted.map((Utxo) => {
      utxos.add(Utxo);
    });
    // Add Input In Our TX
    txBuilder.add_inputs_from(utxos, 2);
    // Add Change Address to Return the Remaining Amount
    txBuilder.add_change_if_needed(lib.Address.from_bech32(Wallet.paymentAddr));
    const tx = txBuilder.build_tx();

    const user = await User.find({ email: "dawar33011@gmail.com" });
    const entropy = await Decrypt(user[0].entropy);
    console.log(entropy);
    const SenderKeys = getPaymentKeyFromEntropy(entropy);
    console.log(SenderKeys);
    const txVkeyWitness = signTxWithTwoWallets(SenderKeys, Wallet, tx);

    const transactionWitnessSet = tx.witness_set();
    transactionWitnessSet.set_vkeys(txVkeyWitness.vkeys());
    console.log(txVkeyWitness.vkeys().len());
    const signedTx = lib.Transaction.new(
      tx.body(),
      transactionWitnessSet,
      tx.auxiliary_data()
    );
    let txhash = await submitTx(Buffer.from(signedTx.to_bytes(), "hex"));
    console.log(txhash);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
 
};
```

**Here is The Code for Signing the Tx With my two different Wallet**

```
export const signTxWithTwoWallets = (wallet1, wallet2, tx) => {
  const rawTx = tx;
  const txWitnessSet = lib.TransactionWitnessSet.new();
  const vkeyWitnesses = lib.Vkeywitnesses.new();
  const txHash = lib.hash_transaction(rawTx.body());
  const vkey = lib.make_vkey_witness(txHash, wallet1.paymentKey);
  vkeyWitnesses.add(vkey);
  const vkey2 = lib.make_vkey_witness(txHash, wallet1.stakeKey);
  vkeyWitnesses.add(vkey2);
  const vkey3 = lib.make_vkey_witness(txHash, wallet2.paymentKey);
  vkeyWitnesses.add(vkey3);
  const vkey4 = lib.make_vkey_witness(txHash, wallet2.stakeKey);
  vkeyWitnesses.add(vkey4);
  txWitnessSet.set_vkeys(vkeyWitnesses);
  return txWitnessSet;
};
```